# Share Android shared preferences between different devices

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an app, that on the first start generates a random user id and password to set up an account on my server and store them in the shared preferences.

I am looking for a way to write this data into the cloud so that if the user installs the app on a second device it will retrieve this account data and use them on the second device as well.

On iOS, this is a trivial task but I am still trying to figure out how to achieve this on Android. I tried an approach with Firestore, but it seems to be able to write to the Firebase database, the user has to log in with Firebase. I assumed being logged in to a Google Account on the device would do this, but I still get invalid permissions back when writing data.

I do not want to force the user to a separate login.

Any ideas on how to approach this task? Is it possible on Android at all?

Answer (score 0):

> I have an app, that on first start generates a random user ID and password to set up an account on my server and store them in the shared preferences.

If you have your own server where you authenticate the users, and you also want to authenticate to Firebase, then I recommend you check:

- [Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth)

> I am looking for a way to write this data into the cloud so that if the user installs the app on a second device it will retrieve this account data and use them on the second device as well.

You just should never simply store the credentials in Firestore. Storing passwords in cleartext is one of the worst security risks you can inflict on your users. You should either use authentication with your custom system or use one of the existing providers, like Google, Facebook, etc.

> I tried an approach with Firestore, but it seems to be able to write to the database, the user has to log in with Firebase.

It's recommended to authenticate the user in Firebase before reading/writing data from/to Firestore because you can secure your database using [Firestore Security Rules](https://Firestore%20Security%20Rules).

P.S. Don't store data in ShartedPreferences because this type of data is stored locally and doesn't persist application uninstalls.

Comment: Obviously I wouldn't store the credentials a plain text. And they would only be stored there to access them, when the user installs the app on a second device, so that they don't have to enter the credentials manually. That's the only reason to store them at all. Data on the server are not sensitive and the credentials are only used to synchronize certain data between two devices (one of them might even be an iOS device) in realtime via my websocket server. I rather would not use the Google account for that because of potential privacy issues.

Comment: In that case, Custom Authentication System can the problem, right?

Comment: I don't think so. The app on the second device would have no knowledge of the successfull login on the first device and the user would have to manually enter the randomly generated userid from the first device. The whole point is to avoid this. Using custom authentication would be a hen - egg problem. The second device must be authenticated with Firebase to get the necessary data to authenticate. Anyway, it would only be a convenience function for the user which works perfectly well on the iOS version of the app, but which is not strictly necessary.

Comment: If there are no sensitive data, you can then save them in Firetore, and read then after from all applications you want.

Comment: Hey Michael. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to do what I want in Android. Your last suggested solution would result in all users using the same credentials, which would be rather pointless. I only want devices logged in to the same Google account to share the data. I probably could solve it by reading the Google account and using it to identify a device that should receive the data. But that brings privacy issues with it. And especially on older devices, where the required permission includes the permission to read the contacts (not needed for the app), this would unsettle users who install it.